# clear form data after submit jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I clear a form data once the submit succeed in jquery?

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
       $('#submit').click(function () {
           $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url: 'final.php',
              data: "user=" + $('#user').val() + "&comment=" + $('#comment').val(),
              success: function (data) {

                  $('#status').html(data);
               }
          });
       });
   });
```

HTML... I need to clear the form data once the form is submitted....Any help would be appreciated.

```
<input type="text" name="user" id="user">
<input type="text" name="comment" id="comment">
<input name="submit"  type="submit" id="submit">
<div id="status">
```

Comment: Where is the actual `form` element? Do you have an actual form?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$('form').find('input[type=text]').val('')`  should do

Call this in the success callback of your Ajax

Comment: I did but it is not working. I put the code after $('#status').html(data);

Comment: Do you have a form in the first place.. Otherwise just use `$('input[type=text]').val('')`

Comment: tried that again, doesn't work. if you mean the <form action=""......></form> I am not using that, it is sending the id to the final.php...

Comment: Because you have not mentioned anything regarding the form... Try this `$(this).closest('form').find('input[type=text]').val('')` .. I doubt the success callback is being fired in the first place. Check you console for errros

Comment: Also `I am not using that, it is sending the id to the final.php.` ?? .. Does not make senses.. Can you explain

Comment: I mean like I have final.php page and I don't have <form></form> on my html page. All I have on the text fields is the name and id attribute. What I mean by sending was, I don't know but the jquery at the top sends the name attribute to final.php and it is working perfectly except that it doesn't clear the data from the text fields.

Comment: Then `$('input[type=text]').val('')` should work for you unless you have any errors on the page

Answer (score 7):

```
 $('#formId').trigger('reset');
```